# Show all user and the current user in 1 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a user_controller.rb like this,

```
def index
  respond_with User.all
end

def show
  respond_with current_user
end
```

And a Angular service that retrieves all the users data,

```
return {
  loadUsers: function() {
    return $http.get('/users.json');
  }
};
```

Would I be able to create a angular service, a rails controller or a combination of both that would give me the json output of the current user?

Or do I need to create a new controller showing the current user?

Comment: You mean that you need something like a yourdomain.com/profile page?

Comment: I'm working with angular, so I would need something like localhost:3000/current_user.json

I've just created a new current_user resource etc. I think I'm just going to run 2 controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

In your routes.rb:

```
get '/profile', to: 'users#profile'
```

In your users_controller.rb:

```
def profile
  # render your json here
end
```

Note: Filter user attributes before sending to the web for security reasons.

Comment: Hey thank you for your input. I didn't know you could set up routes like this! There's a problem though. If I run this code `    def current_user
      respond_with current_user
    end` i get a endless list of errors `app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `current_user'` (refers to the respond_with current_user line. The respond_with current_user does work in index though.

Comment: Cause current_user redefines the current_user method and calls itself. I should have chosen a different name, sorry, let's fix it!